# IOptions does not return settings for appsettings when deployed as docker container

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, autofac, .net-7.0

We have a .NET 7 application, that uses autofac IOC and needs to pull RegionInfo from the appsetting file, in a class library that is part of our solution.  When running locally in Visual Studio, or by using Bridge to Kubernetes the IOptions in the class library are populated and the functionality works as expected.  When deployed to our cluster as a docker container though the options are not returned to the class causing the api to fail.

I have spent hours on this trying various suggestions online with autofac with no solution, and I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction to resolve this.  Here is the code...

StartUp.cs

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "IntegrationService", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.Configure<RegionInformation>(Configuration.GetSection("RegionInfo"));
        services.AddOptions();

        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
```

GlobalDateManager.cs

```
 private readonly ILogger<GlobalDateManager> _logger;
    private readonly RegionInformation _regionInformation;
   
    public GlobalDateManager(IOptions<RegionInformation> regionInformation, ILogger<GlobalDateManager> logging)
    {
        _regionInformation = regionInformation.Value;
        _logger = logging;
       
    }
```

Comment: I would argue that this is not a code problem. It seems that your docker set up misses the values in the corresponding config sources.

Comment: I wish that was the case, I have shelled into the container and have validated that the appsettings does indeed contain the data I am expecting the be there.

Comment: Run the code which will manually try to access this values in config and add that to the logs. The fact you see appsettings does not mean that they read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but having looked again in some depth, my appsettings.json is being used in StartUp.cs, we have two services setup with connection strings based off entries in the appsettings file these being SQL Server Connection string as well as a connection string for a service used by the HttpClientFactory.   I also hardcoded region values where they are required and the application now works.  Therefore it seems that outside StartUp.cs i.e. Controllers and class libraries the values are not picked up.

Comment: Probably your `Program.cs` has call to `AddEnvironmentVariables()` and cluster's environment value overrides your config value.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple webapi using part of your code.
It uses the IOptions pattern like your code does, and it outputs the configuration.

It was created launching the simple command `dotnet new webapi -o abcde`

Here the entire files i changed or created:

**Program.cs (changed)**

```js
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Autofac;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// start of your snippet code
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "IntegrationService", Version = "v1" });
        });
services.Configure<RegionInformation>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RegionInfo"));
services.AddOptions();
var container = new  ContainerBuilder(); // added this line of your code: anyway i did not used it in the app
// end of your snippet code

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**RegionInformation.cs (created)**

```js
public class RegionInformation{

    public const string RegionInfo = "RegionInfo";

    public string Name {get;set;} = string.Empty;
}
```

**Controllers/GetConfigAndOptionsController.cs (created)**

```js
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
namespace abcde.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GetConfigAndOptionsController : ControllerBase
{   
    private readonly ILogger<GetConfigAndOptionsController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly  IOptions<RegionInformation> _regionInformation;

    public GetConfigAndOptionsController(ILogger<GetConfigAndOptionsController> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<RegionInformation> regionInformation )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _regionInformation = regionInformation;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetGetConfigAndOptions")]
    public string Get()
    {
        var sb = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        sb.WriteLine("Listing all providers (appsettings.json should be present in the list))\n");
             
        // listing all providers
        foreach (var provider in ((IConfigurationRoot)_configuration).Providers.ToList())
        {
            sb.WriteLine(provider.ToString());
        }    

        // getting the Name using the configuration object
        sb.WriteLine($"\nFrom config: {_configuration["RegionInfo:Name"]}");

        // or getting the value using IOption like your code does
        sb.WriteLine($"\nFrom IOptions: {_regionInformation.Value.Name}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json (changed)**

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  
  "RegionInfo":{
    "Name":"kiggyttass"
  }
}
```

Finally i created a simple **Dockerfile**

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /App

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "abcde.dll"]
```

Then,

```bash
# build your docker image
docker build -t abcde .  

# run it
docker run --name=abcde --rm  -p 9234:80  abcde
```

Call the corresponding GET method in the Swagger UI, or cUrl to http://localhost:9234/GetConfigAndOptions

and you should get something like this:

```
Listing all providers (appsettings.json should be present in the list))

MemoryConfigurationProvider
EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider Prefix: 'ASPNETCORE_'
MemoryConfigurationProvider
EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider Prefix: 'DOTNET_'
JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.json' (Optional)
JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.Production.json' (Optional)
EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider Prefix: ''
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider

From config: kiggyttass

From IOptions: kiggyttass
```

Try to create this dockerized application and check if you get a similar output.
You should get your value using IConfiguration or IOptions.

Hope it helps.